# Access object properties from lists via asp .net object data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

If I have an ObjectDataSource that returns Person who has a property FavoutieColoirs as a List, can I access one of those Colours for display, via some notation in the ASP markup?

i.e. if Person has had a Name property, I can use

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
```

Can I use something like

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Colours[0]") %>
```

Or maybe even

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Colours.Select(x => x.ColourName == 'Blue')" %>
```

(Pretty sure the last one doesn't work, but I'm hoping there's some way to implement the second).

If I can't do that and want to diaply the 'first item in a List' (say) do I have to add a method to Person for 'FirstFavouriteColour' that returns a single item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation at [DataBinder.Eval Method (Object, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx) is quite clear about this:

> Expression: The navigation path from the container object to the public property
>   value to be placed in the bound control property. This must be a
>   string of property or field names separated by periods, such as
>   Tables[0].DefaultView.[0].Price in C# or
>   Tables(0).DefaultView.(0).Price in Visual Basic

So the second expression should work fine if Colours has an indexer (`this[int index]`) property defined.